# Unbinding the click event that involves jquery removal from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know unbinding events is well-established, but for some reason this isn't working. If the "trash_mode" method is called it attaches an event handler to "my_div", such that when those divs are clicked they are removed from the DOM:

```
function trash_mode() {
    $('#my_div').click(function remove_from_dom(){
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var use_id = "#" + id;
                $(use_id).remove();
                });
}
```

This works great. Then, I want to call the "trash_mode" method again to remove this event handler from the divs. So for example, I might try:

```
$('#my_div').off("click", "remove_from_dom");
```

when the function is called again (using some kind of toggle mechanism). But this doesn't work...the divs still get removed from DOM (the click event is still attached).

Is there a way to toggle between the "remove_from_dom" method (on and off) each time the "trash_mode" method is called?

Comment: create jsfiddle please

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery API docs say that the second parameter of the `.off()` function is a selector, not a name of the handler.

[API Doc](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

It seems like what you want might be best done by calling the `.off()` function on some parent element of all the divs and using that second parameter to select them.

```
$('#my_div_parent').off("click", "#my_div");
```

The documentation also notes that the `.off()` function is meant to be paired with `.on()`, so if you're still unable to remove the event handlers, you might try changing the way you attach the event handler in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up using an if-else statement inside the on() method.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work was to put an if-else statement inside jquery's ".on()" method, like this:

```
<button onclick="trash_mode()">TOGGLE TRASH MODE</button>

var count = 0;
function trash_mode()
$("#my_div").on( "click", function() {
                  var id = $(this).attr('id');
                  var use_id = "#" + id;
                  if(count != 0){
                     $(use_id).remove();
                     count=0;
                  } else { 
                    count++;
                  }
                  }); 
}
```

Now, each time you click the button it will toggle the remove() event handler between enabled/disabled.